# Count duplicates and update table with a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which has several thousand records.
I want to update all the records which have a duplicate firstname
How can I achieve this with a single query?
Sample table structure:

```
Fname varchar(100)
Lname varchar(100)
Duplicates int
```

This duplicate column must be updated with the total number of duplicates with a single query.
Is this possible without running in a loop?

Comment: Can you show some sample data <--> desired output?

Answer (score 2):

```
update table as t1
inner join ( 
select
fname,
count(fname) as total
from table
group by fname) as t2
on t1.fname = t2.fname
set t1.duplicates = t2.total
```

Comment: Apologies!  It just appeared to violate that constraint.  Weird.

Comment: I tried the above query, but I was unable to view the results. I have close to 200,000 records, after a while it was hanging so I had to kill the process. Is there  way to limit the records? I just want to test the above query for say 1000 records.

Comment: Add a limit clause after group by clause and retry. You can even try do add an index on fname field in order to speed up your query.

Comment: I added a limit clause but even then just to process 1000 records its taking several minutes and its not completing I had to kill the process. Any ways to quicken the process?

Comment: I am unable to process 200,000 records. Any ways to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a table which has several thousand records. I want to update all the records which have a duplicate firstname How can I achieve this with a single query?

Are you absolutely sure you want to *store* the number of the so called duplicates? If not, it's a rather simple query:

```
SELECT fname, COUNT(1) AS number FROM yourtable GROUP BY fname;
```

I don't see why you would want to store that number though. What if there's another record inserted? What if there are records deleted? The "number of duplicates" will remain the same, and therefore will become incorrect at the first mutation.

Comment: True, but I want to view the list of duplicates and then delete the ones I don't need. So if I process all the duplicates, it makes it easier. I might be running this "check for duplicates" process once in two weeks.

Comment: Also your query doesn't list by duplicates, it simply lists all records.

Comment: @KrishnaIyer - Try adding a having clause ie `HAVING COUNT(1) > 1` But if the ultimate goal is deleting duplicates, you need additional logic because that would not tell you which record to "keep".

Comment: @KrishnaIyer How about, instead of executing a query to remove duplicates once in a while, you opt for a UNIQUE constraint in your database instead? My query indeed doesn't list duplicates, but like @Leigh mentioned, that's easily solved by a `HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`.

Comment: Good point. "An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure" :)

Comment: I want to allow duplicates, its easy to prevent duplicates though.

Answer (score 0):

Create the column first, then write a query like:

```
UPDATE table SET table.duplicates = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table r GROUP BY Fname/Lname/some_id)
```

Maybe this other SO will help?

[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select)

Comment: [Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Comment: In MSSQL, and using aliases, you can.

Comment: Lovely.  :)   But the question is tagged [tag:mysql].

Comment: Didn't you just agree that nick rulez's answer was correct?  And doesn't he have a select in a subquery that hits the same table as his update?  And doesn't it use a similar method to what I linked to?  And thusly couldn't you put this all together to say that in MySQL you can update a table and select from the same table in a subquery using an inner join as explained by nick?

Comment: [You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause: UPDATE `table` SET `table`.duplicates = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` r GROUP BY `some_id`)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75ad7/1)

Comment: True :) my code was pseudo and not something I tested using his tables from his MySQL Server :).  No need to argue, it's really just semantics.  What I was implying does work, what I wrote does not -- you are right.

Answer (score -1):

You might not be able to do this. You can't update the same table that you are selecting from in the same query.

Comment: Yes you can.  Use the multiple-table update syntax with a self-join (like I just did in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10399092/623041)).

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html "Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."

Comment: @ethrbunny Not if you don't use the self-join hack. If you use that, it is possible.